# Prolog FindAll with a range of particular values

Tags: prolog

I am attempting to use findall, but I want one of the values of the argument to be a range of values. I have seen another post utilizing 'between' but I can't seem to get it to work. This is the code I want to alter:

```
lists(A):-
    findall(X,gradrate(2011,_,X),A).
```

I want essentially:

```
lists(A):-
    findall(X,gradrate(2011-2015,_,X),A).
```

Basically I want a list of all the graduation rates between years 2011 and 2015. I have a bunch of facts already written with all the gradrates I.E

```
gradrate(2011,asian,85.6).
```

Any point in the right direction would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
lists(A):-
    findall( X, 
             ( gradrate(Year, _, X),
               between(2011, 2015, Year) ),
             A ).
```

Comment: dude you have no idea, ive been struggling on this for way too long ! thanks!